# QSoundEffect() doesn't play sounds when it's out of global scope

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm making an app which copy files from one directory to another. I want it to produce sound when the process finishes. I can't figure out how to make QSoundEffect produce sounds when it's inside some function or class. The only time it works is when the code looks like the following:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = QMainWindow()

filepath = "C:\Windows\Media\Windows Error.wav"
sound = QSoundEffect()
sound.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(filepath))
sound.play()
    
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Why doesn't it work when code looks like that? How to make it work in a function or a class?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *


def play_sound():
    filepath = "C:\Windows\Media\Windows Error.wav"
    sound = QSoundEffect()
    sound.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(filepath))
    sound.play()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = QMainWindow()
    
play_sound()

win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: As you already pointed out my answer, it solves the problem that you pointed out in your post, so if you have another problem (the implementation of the solution in threads) then you must create another post since this is the correct operation of SO. Please read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: Imagine that the OP changes his question every time the solution no longer works in a new scenario, that would make it never solve the posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that "sound" is a local variable of the play_sound function so it will be eliminated when that method finishes executing which is almost instantaneous.

The solution is to extend the life cycle:

- Python style: use a global variable

  ```py
  sound = None

  def play_sound():
      filepath = "C:\Windows\Media\Windows Error.wav"
      global sound
      sound = QSoundEffect()
      sound.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(filepath))
      sound.play()
  ```
- Qt style: set a parent

  ```py
  def play_sound():
      filepath = "C:\Windows\Media\Windows Error.wav"
      sound = QSoundEffect(QCoreApplication.instance())
      sound.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(filepath))
      sound.play()
  ```